# Couchdb from nodeJS gives 404 on non-existing document instead of usual error object

Tags: node.js, couchdb

When I request a non existing document in a database using curl I get the following message as specified in the doc :

```
{"error":"not_found","reason":"missing"}
```

However from my node app when I request the same url with http.get, or with nano.db.get I get a 404 error.

```
Request Failed
Status Code: 404
```

I found that in earlier versions it was the "normal" behavior but I am up to date. Any idea ?

Comment: If you examine the json payload of the error response from http.get, or with nano.db.get, you'll see the same {"error":"not_found","reason":"missing"}.

Comment: But if I go to the URL I have a json object, so what is the intermediate layer?